# Get IDs from an Array with variable length / field to class?

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist, checkbox

I have a `public class User` which has a field `int userID`. Multiple `User` objects are stored in another class, `SharedFlat`, in an `ArrayList<User>`. In the Activity, I want to create and display a CheckBox for each `User` object in the `ArrayList<User>`. Since the number of Users in the ArrayList, thus also the number of CheckBoxes, is variable, I've used a for-loop and the `setID()`-method to set the `userID` of the current User object to be the ID of the corresponding CheckBox:

```
  /* This method displays the CheckBoxes with the user names to the R.layout.new_payment_screen layout file */
private void createCheckboxes(SharedFlat flat) {
    // Find the layout and create a Checkbox Array to store all users
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.who_received);
    final CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[flat.getNumberOfUsers()];
    // Create a new Checkbox for each user and set the users name to it
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        // create new checkboxes
        checkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        // add checkboxes to the layout
        ll.addView(checkBoxes[i]);
        // set text of the CheckBox to be userName of current User object
        checkBoxes[i].setText(flat.getSpecificUserName(i));
        // set the ID to be the userID of the corresponding User
        checkBoxes[i].setId(flat.getSpecificUserID(i));
    }
}
```

This seems to work, the CheckBoxes and corresponding userNames are correctly displayed. (Question: is there a better solution?)

Now to the real Problem: I have a Button that's supposed to check which CheckBoxes are checked (with `.isChecked()`), because I later have to work on with the `User` objects that have been "checked" at the time the `onClick()` method of the button was called.
Since I have to get the complete `User` objects that have been checked, and not only their `userID`s, is there a way I can get the `User` object by only having the `User`s variable `userID`? Would anyone have suggestion how I could solve this better?
I think I found a way to find at least the `userIDs` of the checked `User` object, but I'm not quite sure if this will work out for all scenarios:

```
 // Find the CheckBoxes within the LinearLayout and search them for the checked ones (= Receivers)
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.who_received);
    final int checkBoxCount = ll.getChildCount();
    ArrayList<Integer> userIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxCount; i++) {
        CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) ll.getChildAt(i);
        if (currentCheckBox.isChecked()) {
            userIdList.add(i);
        }
    }
```

Or if someone has a completely different solution - I "just" need to create CheckBoxes and attach IDs to them, but I don't how many CheckBoxes will be there (depends on number of `users`)
Would be awesome if someone could help me. As you can tell, I'm quite new into programming - freshman :-)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have a solution for what you call your real problem to be, i.e. getting to the instance of the specific `User` object "attached" to the `CheckBox`. Well, it's actually attaching (without the quotes) the object to the `CheckBox` via the `setTag()` method in your initial `for` loop. You say you have the list of `User` objects in the `SharedFlat` class. So I assume you have (or can add) a method to get the `User` object by index like so `flat.getUser(i)`.
Then you can add this line in your initial `for` loop.

```
checkBoxes[i].setTag(flat.getUser(i));
```

So it will look something like this.

```
  /* This method displays the CheckBoxes with the user names to the R.layout.new_payment_screen layout file */
private void createCheckboxes(SharedFlat flat) {
    // Find the layout and create a Checkbox Array to store all users
    LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.who_received);
    final CheckBox[] checkBoxes = new CheckBox[flat.getNumberOfUsers()];
    // Create a new Checkbox for each user and set the users name to it
    for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++) {
        // create new checkboxes
        checkBoxes[i] = new CheckBox(this);
        // add checkboxes to the layout
        ll.addView(checkBoxes[i]);
        // set text of the CheckBox to be userName of current User object
        checkBoxes[i].setText(flat.getSpecificUserName(i));
        // set the ID to be the userID of the corresponding User
        checkBoxes[i].setId(flat.getSpecificUserID(i));
        checkBoxes[i].setTag(flat.getUser(i));
    }
}
```

This way, you are effectively attaching a whole `User` object to the respective `CheckBox` (instead of only linking them with IDs) which you can later retrieve by using the `getTag()` method on each `CheckBox`. I'm not sure if you'll need the id of the `CheckBox` to match with the `userID` at all.

So, your next piece of code would like this

```
// Find the CheckBoxes within the LinearLayout and search them for the checked ones (= Receivers)
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.who_received);
final int checkBoxCount = ll.getChildCount();
ArrayList<User> users = new ArrayList<User>();
for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxCount; i++) {
    CheckBox currentCheckBox = (CheckBox) ll.getChildAt(i);
    if (currentCheckBox.isChecked()) {
        users.add((User)currentCheckBox.getTag());
    }
}
```

And you'll have the list of `User` objects named users whose respective `CheckBox`es have been checked.

Comment: Awesome, it works! Great idea with the `setTag` and `getTag` methods, I didn't know about them yet. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: P.S.: your help saved me 15-20 lines of code, including a very makeshift, confusing method. Thanks again, great job! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track with everything. For the first issue, using a for-loop is going to be the best way to set up your checkboxes. One optimization you could do is check which ones are checked when you are displaying them if that is even an option for you. Otherwise, you can just check the which boxes have checks and put those id's into an array, then check that id against your array of User values.